# Can I convert between UpperCamelCase, lowerCamelCase and dash-case in filenemes with Bash?

Tags: bash, camelcasing

I am in the process of merging efforts with another developer. I am using UpperCamelCasing, but we decided to follow [Google's HTML style guide in using lower case and separating words with hyphens](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/htmlcssguide.xml?showone=ID_and_Class_Name_Delimiters#ID_and_Class_Name_Delimiters). This decision requires me to rename quite some files on my filesystem. I first though this to be easy since I often use bash for renaming large collections of files. Unfortunately renaming on the Casing style appeared to be a bit more complicating and I did not manage to find an approach.

Can I convert files from one naming convention to another with Bash?

Comment: I think you are talking about file renaming. And the SO question link you see is converting file contents.

Comment: Almost. You want to do this operation on an entire folder structure. So you'll want to combine it with a sutiable `find` command.

Answer (score 8):

Try using `rename` command with `-f` option to rename files with desired substitutions.

```
rename -f 's/([a-z])([A-Z])/$1-$2/g; y/A-Z/a-z/' <list_of_files>
```

If you also want to extract `<list_of_files>` with some pattern, let's say extension `.ext`, you need to combine `find` with above command using `xargs`

```
find -type f -name "*.ext" -print0 | xargs -0 rename -f 's/([a-z])([A-Z])/$1-$2/g; y/A-Z/a-z/'
```

For example if you want to rename all files in `pwd`

```
$ ls
dash-case
lowerCamelCase
UpperCamelCase

$ rename -f 's/([a-z])([A-Z])/$1-$2/g; y/A-Z/a-z/' *

$ ls
dash-case
lower-camel-case
upper-camel-case
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for FILE in *; do NEWFILE=$((sed -re 's/\B([A-Z])/-\1/g' | tr [:upper:] [:lower:]) <<< "$FILE"); if [ "$NEWFILE" != "$FILE" ]; then echo mv \""$FILE"\" \""$NEWFILE"\"; fi; done
```

This should give you a list of "mv" statements on standard output. Double-check that they look right, then just add `| bash` to the end of the statement to run them all.

How does it work?

```
for FILE in *; do
  NEWFILE=$((sed -re 's/\B([A-Z])/-\1/g' | tr [:upper:] [:lower:]) <<< "$FILE")
  if [ "$NEWFILE" != "$FILE" ]; then
    echo mv \""$FILE"\" \""$NEWFILE"\"
  fi
done
```

The `for FILE in *` loops across all files in the current directory, acknowledging that there are a wide variety of ways to loop through all files. The sed statement matches only uppercase letters that, according to `\B`, aren't on a word boundary (i.e. at the beginning of the string). Because of this selective match, it makes the most sense to switch everything to lowercase in a separate call to `tr`. Finally, the condition ensures that you only see the filenames that change, and the trick of using `echo` ensures that you don't make changes to your filesystem without seeing them first.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502977/linux-bash-camel-case-string-to-separate-by-dash) and based on one answer there I came to the following solution. It is not a full  Bash solution, since it relies on perl, but since it does the trick I am sharing it.

```
ls  |for file in `xargs`; do mv $file `echo $file | perl -ne 'print lc(join("-", split(/(?=[A-Z])/)))'`; done
```

Comment: The Perl snippet is moderately useful but the shell loop is a grab bag of antipatterns so dense that I'm simply downvoting this and deferring to http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls to fix at least the worst offenses.  See also http://shellcheck.net/