# Spinal Case to Camel Case

Tags: bash, sed

My question is pretty much the opposite of this: [linux bash, camel case string to separate by dash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502977/linux-bash-camel-case-string-to-separate-by-dash)

Pretty much looking to take `some-string-like-this` to `SomeStringLikeThis`.

Anyone got some `sed` magic or other means of doing this easily?

As a side note, part of me thinks that as popular as Bash is, that there might be a library out there that could help with conversions like this... I haven't found one though. If you know of one, please let me know. e.g. a library that would handle common string manipulations/conversion between standard naming styles, such as spinal to underscore, underscore to camel, camel to spinal, etc.

Comment: I know this is old, but if you start the string with a capital letter, it's called PascalCase not camelCase. Just for anyone else finding this.

Comment: Or upper camel case

Answer (score 32, accepted):

## GNU sed

This works with GNU sed:

```
sed -r 's/(^|-)(\w)/\U\2/g'
```

Match the start of the line or a `-` followed by an alphanumeric character and use `\U` to make the character uppercase.

And here's how you can operate on a variable with it and assign the result to another variable:

```
name_upper=$(sed -r 's/(^|-)(\w)/\U\2/g' <<<"$name_spinal")
```

## Perl

It's almost identical in perl:

```
perl -pe 's/(^|-)(\w)/\U$2/g'
```

## Native bash

Just for fun, here's a way you could do it in native bash:

```
spinal_to_upper() {
    IFS=- read -ra str <<<"$1"
    printf '%s' "${str[@]^}"
}

spinal_to_upper "some-string-like-this"
```

Comment: The bash solution does not work on Mac with default bash 3.2.57. Perl seems the most portable way.

Comment: The `sed` version isn't working for me.

Comment: @NoelYap are you using GNU sed? Running `sed` with no arguments should give you a clue. If not, it's unlikely to work, since it uses a few extensions that aren't available in other versions. The Perl version is more portable.

Comment: The Native Bash solution is quite elegant. I like it.

Answer (score -8):

its very easy

```
   $string='this-is-a-string' ;

   echo   str_replace('-', '', ucwords($string, "-"));
```

output ThisIsAString

Comment: I'm sorry but isn't this PHP instead of bash? I believe the poster was asking for bash.