# How to rename files to param-case in Bash

Tags: string, bash

How to rename a bunch of files in a directory to be `param-case` with the hyphen?

[Here's](https://github.com/blakeembrey/no-case/blob/master/no-case.js) one that does it in JavaScript, but I'm not sure how to go about this in bash.

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502977/linux-bash-camel-case-string-to-separate-by-dash

Comment: Why not use `node.js`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an option in bash:

```
for file in ./* ; do mv "$file" "$(echo $file | sed 's/\(.\)\([A-Z]\)/\1-\2/g' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')" ; done
```

An alternative with perl:

```
for file in ./* ; do mv "$file" "$(echo $file | perl -ne 'print lc(join("-", split(/(?=[A-Z])/)))')" ; done
```