# zmv - do not change case if there are more than one consecutive uppercase letters

Tags: zsh

I am using the [following command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62845581/1772898)

```
zmv -n -Q '(**/)(*[[:upper:]]*)(/)' '${1}${(L)${2//(#b)([[:upper:]])/-$match[1]}#-}'
```

to transform

```
% tree
.
├── EmptyFile.txt
├── FirstDirectoryName
│   ├── FourthDirectoryName
│   ├── secondDirectoryName
│   └── thirdDirectoryName
├── FourthDirectoryName
├── secondDirectoryName
└── thirdDirectoryName
```

To

```
% tree
.
├── EmptyFile.txt
├── first-directory-name
│   ├── fourth-directory-name
│   ├── second-directory-name
│   └── third-directory-name
├── fourth-directory-name
├── second-directory-name
└── third-directory-name
```

However there is a small problem.

I do not want to lowercase if there are more than one consecutive uppercase letters. I just want to put `-` behind the capital letters given it is not in the beginning.

```
% tree
.
├── DDDDDDD
├── FirstFolderToRename
│   ├── DDDDDDD
│   └── ThisIsDDDDD
├── secondFolderToRename
│   ├── DDDDDDD
│   └── ThisIsDDDDD
└── ThisIsDDDDD
```

Current Output

```
% zmv -n -Q '(**/)(*[[:upper:]]*)(/)' '${1}${(L)${2//(#b)([[:upper:]])/-$match[1]}#-}'
mv -- FirstFolderToRename/DDDDDDD FirstFolderToRename/d-d-d-d-d-d-d
mv -- FirstFolderToRename/ThisIsDDDDD FirstFolderToRename/this-is-d-d-d-d-d
mv -- secondFolderToRename/DDDDDDD secondFolderToRename/d-d-d-d-d-d-d
mv -- secondFolderToRename/ThisIsDDDDD secondFolderToRename/this-is-d-d-d-d-d
mv -- DDDDDDD d-d-d-d-d-d-d
mv -- FirstFolderToRename first-folder-to-rename
mv -- secondFolderToRename second-folder-to-rename
mv -- ThisIsDDDDD this-is-d-d-d-d-d
```

Expected Output

```
mv -- FirstFolderToRename/DDDDDDD FirstFolderToRename/DDDDDDD
mv -- FirstFolderToRename/ThisIsDDDDD FirstFolderToRename/this-is-DDDDD
mv -- secondFolderToRename/DDDDDDD secondFolderToRename/DDDDDDD
mv -- secondFolderToRename/ThisIsDDDDD secondFolderToRename/this-is-DDDDD
mv -- DDDDDDD DDDDDDD
mv -- FirstFolderToRename first-folder-to-rename
mv -- secondFolderToRename second-folder-to-rename
mv -- ThisIsDDDDD this-is-DDDDD
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [linuxquestions](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/zsh-zmv-do-not-change-case-if-there-are-more-than-one-consecutive-uppercase-letters-4175678542/)

```
function CamelOrPascalToKebab() {

    zmv -Q '(**/)(*[A-Z]*)(/)' '$1${2//(#b)([a-z])([A-Z])/$match[1]-$match[2]}'
    zmv -Q '(**/)(*[A-Z][a-z]*)(/)' '$1${2//(#m)[A-Z][a-z]/${(L)MATCH}}'

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Specify `one or more upper case characters`. That is `[[:upper:]]##` with zsh's extended globbing (which zmv uses). `##` is similar to regex `+` quantifier. A single `#` is `zero or more`, similar to regex `*`.

```
zmv -n -Q '(**/)(*[[:upper:]]*)(/)' '${1}${(L)${2//(#b)([[:upper:]]##)/-$match[1]}#-}'
```

Optionally, convert leading upper case characters separately instead of removing initial `-` afterwards:

```
${1}${(LM)2##[[:upper:]]#}${(L)${2##[[:upper:]]#}//(#b)([[:upper:]]##)/-$match[1]}
```

Comment: This answer is not working. I will In-Shah-Allah accept it if the solution works.